# Repeatedly call a function in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a fragment that stems off the main activity. I am trying to have a textbox update with the users GPS location as they move around. I currently have it so every time you resume the fragment it updates, but I would like it to happen automatically every 10 seconds or so.

I am currently attempting to use runOnUiThread, which didn't cause my app to crash but didn't seem to do anything.

Within the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   TextView newText = getView().findViewById(R.id.wText);
   newText.setText(getStringCoordinates);
   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                 
               newText.setText(getStringCoordinates);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have a callback function listening for GPS location updates. I would suggest using that function to pass the updated information to your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a handler, something like this should work

```
private Handler myHandler;
private static final int DELAY = 10000;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    checkAgain();
}

private void checkAgain() {
    myHandler.postDelayed(()-> checkGps(),DELAY);
}

private void checkGps() {
    //do stuff here
    checkAgain();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    myHandler = null;
}
```

basically it sends a message to the main thread every 10 seconds to check gps

the code may be wrong cause I'm writing it off the top of my head, but it should give you a good start

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is working

```
public class c_Thread_Update_Fragment extends Thread {

int i =0;

 c_Thread_Update_Fragment(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager vp)
    {
        this.fragmentManager =fm;
        this.mViewpager =vp;
    }

 @Override
    public void run() {
while(true)
{
    f.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
         yourfragmentclass.updateData(i);

            }               
         });

     i++;
sleep(1000);


}

}

       public static void setFragment(Fragment f){
        f =f;
        }

}
```

1. Implement a `public static void update (xxx){}` in yourfragmentclass
2. Use `setFragment(f)` in your Fragment adapterclass and pass the current fragment.

Comment: I'm in a hurry and if this is not enough I will replay tomorrow.